# Javascript: How to extract the onclick function in a button to text?

Tags: javascript

I've targeted a button and the onclick attribute contains a function call with a huge js/json object as its argument.

Inside that object, there is a url that I can extract, if I can just turn the .onclick value into a plain text string.

How to do?

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary')[3].???(onclick)
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getAttribute` method will let you read a string value from an element's attribute (whereas the `onclick` property will give you a function).

If you have control over the site then it would probably be better to do some refactoring and move the URL into a `data-*` attribute which you can access from both the `onclick` script and the other script.

Comment: it is a work site that I don't control - I just want the url buried inside the button code so I can modify the page with my own user script

Comment: getAttribute("onclick") did the job
Thanks!